# Installing gcc without root?

Tags: osx, gcc, non-root-user

I'm running OSX, and I don't have root, or an existing compiler. Is there any way I can install gcc?

1. Are there official or trusted unofficial mach-o binaries that can be downloaded for a certain version of OS X?
2. If so, can said binaries be installed to `~/bin` and work properly?

Comment: Why not compile the version you need?

Comment: @Karlson because I don't have a compiler, it's in the question `:P`

Comment: Do you have access to a different machine? If you are really desperate you could compile on a different one and move the result over. Even cross compilation from a different unix might be possible, but i'd recommend rebuilding the toolchain afterwards. There are certainly free gccs to be had on the internet for the latest OSXs (for example http://hpc.sourceforge.net/index.php) but if i recall correctly those have hard coded /usr/local paths and worse, you still don't have binutils and I don't believe there is a source other than the xcode bundle.

Comment: @Max I have access to Linux. Is there a way to build a binary for mach-o on Linux?

Comment: There are a handful of crosscompiling guides out there.
http://devs.openttd.org/~truebrain/compile-farm/apple-darwin9.txt
This looks somewhat promising, albeit painful. If there is any way to get your admin to just install xcode for you, I'd recommend that. This will not be easy.

Comment: @Max last time I went in her office, she did a "virus scan" that searched only images, videos, and my web history, then lectured me about the evils of BitTorrent and threatened to call the authorities, and installed a keylogger. I'd rather write my own Linux distro that is macho-compatible than go through that again. EDIT: What's funny is, I went in there to get Python upgraded, and this IT professional specializing in OS X didn't know what the terminal was. Anyway, I'll look through that guide, the first few paragraphs look promising.

Comment: I imagine you could install VirtualBox or VmWare on Mac OS X and run GNU/Linux (with full root permissions) under that?

Comment: @CharlesBoyd I've tried VirtualBox, and it requires admin to install. Don't have VMWare, but I'd imagine it would be the same. I have Linux on another computer, what difference would it make?

Comment: Just ask the Administrator to install XCode, from the App Store, will save many hours of hacking.

Comment: See my last few posts. I asked a few years ago, and she was convinced it was some low-orbit-ion-cannon type of "destruction tool". Last time I was in her office, my computer was searched and had a keylogger installed because I'm a "threat".

Long story short, not an option.

Comment: You can't fix stupid.... :(

Comment: Forget it. If it goes against _explicit_ policy, trying to bypass the restrictions only will end you up in deep, deep, dodo. Better hack away at your own machine, that should be plenty.

Comment: @vonbrand her explicit policy is "if it involves a terminal, it scares me", by that policy half my school work goes against explicit policy.

Comment: @tkbx, that might be so, and it might be over the top. But better keep clear of meddling in the affairs of The Powers That Be. Your energies are better spent elsewhere, where it doesn't get you in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the gcc precompiled binaries from here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

They come as a pkg, you can follow the instructions here: ["How can I open a .pkg file manually?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15658/how-can-i-open-a-pkg-file-manually) to install the pkg as an unprivileged user.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like [Gentoo Prefix](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/) for Mac OS X, which allows you to bootstrap a Gentoo environment under your home directory (or anywhere else you may want it where you have read/write/execute permissions).

From the description:

> Gentoo Prefix runs unprivileged, meaning no root user or rights are
>   required to use it.

Just a note though - I have never personally gotten this to work (it failed a few times and I lost patience). However, I do know it is actively maintained and bug reports are usually replied to very quickly. The IRC channel is also quite helpful.

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately for this use case, bootstrapping Gentoo Prefix requires that the host already have a compiler installed.